# No Input Device after logging in user on Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: ubuntu, thinkpad, microphone

Hello I am having a weird problem, i say weird because of my lack of technical experience.

my Lenovo-Thinkpad T450 runs Ubuntu 23.04 (Lunar Lobster). usually the F4 key on this machine will handel muting/unmuting the Microphone, the thing is before I log into my user account on the login interface when I press F4 is working properly, after logging in the key does not work anymore and in Settings -> Sounds shows no input device. i created a new user and when I log into that new user every thing is working properly.

so from here I don't know where to start debugging this, I would really appreciate it if someone has knowledge and could help me in debugging this issue and maybe find a solution.

what I found on internet to debug the issue:

```
User[no-input]$ arecord -l
     **** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
    card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC3232 Analog [ALC3232 Analog]
      Subdevices: 1/1
      Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
    
User[no-input]$ cat /proc/asound/card*/codec* | grep Codec
      Codec: Intel Broadwell HDMI
      Codec: Realtek ALC3232
```

then i went [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/sound/hd-audio/models.html) and tried to find a module to edit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf and from the modules i thought they should work for my machine nothing seemed to do any positive change

checking dmesg for loaded input devices after booting up

```
User[no-input]$ sudo dmesg -wH
    [  +0,088443] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0: autoconfig for ALC3232: line_outs=1 (0x14/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:speaker                                      
    [  +0,000006] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)                                                                      
    [  +0,000002] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:    hp_outs=2 (0x16/0x15/0x0/0x0/0x0)                                                                         
    [  +0,000002] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0                                                                                        
    [  +0,000001] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:    inputs:                                                                                                   
    [  +0,000002] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:      Dock Mic=0x19                                                                                           
    [  +0,000001] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:      Mic=0x1a                                                                                                
    [  +0,000002] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:      Internal Mic=0x12     
    [  +0,072823] input: HDA Intel PCH Dock Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1/input18
    [  +0,000106] input: HDA Intel PCH Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1/input19
    [  +0,013638] input: HDA Intel PCH Dock Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1/input20
    [  +0,000109] input: HDA Intel PCH Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1/input21
```

from the above I guess this is why the button is working before logging in, I am not able to find whats happening after logging in

Comment: cross-posted: https://serverfault.com/questions/1132062/no-input-device-after-logging-in-user-on-ubuntu-23-04 , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/747292/no-input-device-after-logging-in-user-on-ubuntu-23-04 , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76346825/no-input-device-after-logging-in-user-on-ubuntu23-04 , and (where it should probably belong): https://askubuntu.com/questions/1469700/no-input-device-after-logging-in-user-on-ubuntu-23-04